# Azure Website filling up with mdmp files

Tags: tomcat, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am hosting a Tomcat application on Azure Websites, and whenever it crashes Azure writes a 200MB+ .mdmp file to my wwwroot directory. Several of these, and my application goes over its space limit.

Is there a way to disable this? Is there a Tomcat or Azure setting I have enabled to accidentally turn this on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-XX:-CreateMinidumpOnCrash option in JAVA_OPTS env variable will prevent the minidumps from being created.

Comment: Thanks - I have updated my JAVA_OPTS variable in my web.config file.